# Cannot resolve method with (android.content.context)?

Tags: picasso, android-context, android-contentresolver

Cannot resolve method with(android.content.context)

```
 Picasso.with(context).load(url).placeholder(R.drawable.placeholder).into(thumbnail);
```

What will be the problem? The error shows "With".

Answer (score 2):

If you are using version 3.0.0-SNAPSHOT or 2.71828 you must use get() instead of with().

`Picasso.get().load(url).placeholder(R.drawable.placeholder).into(thumbnail);`

There are no release notes yet but you can see the commit here: [Commit](https://github.com/square/picasso/commit/e7e919232fe2b15772a7fcd9e15ead2304c66fae)